# show SharePoint log in web site

Tags: sharepoint-server, logs

Any ideas how to display SharePoint log and SharePoint event viewer log on the web site?

I need to trace logs without access SharePoint server

Thanks

Comment: easier said than done, since it's multiple text files spread out across (potentially) multiple servers. This is assuming on-prem SharePoint of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the beginning of the year there is no way to do it anymore. Microsoft changed that so you need to contact them to get the required information. The best way will be to contact Microsoft Support.

Sorry :(

but in SharePoint 2013 you can use this function:

```
var entries = new SPULSRetriever(forwardCheckTimeInMinutes, maxEntries, DateTime startTime);
```

Comment: Thanks macro, what about sharepoint server?  I am using sharepoint on premises

Comment: are you using sharepoint 2013?? for 2010 the answer is diferente

Comment: Yes, It is 2013

Comment: I edit my answer